# Tags on homepage grid won't center if the tags do not go over 2 lines

Tags: php, css, wordpress

My homepage is in a grid format and each post shows all tags related to that post ([ProgressionFantasy](https://progressionfantasy.co.uk/)). I would like all tags and other taxonomies to be centred. I have used the **div align="center"** code which centre's the tags, but I've noticed that it only centre's them if there are too many tags to fit on 1 line. As long as at least one of my taxonomies has enough terms to cover 2 lines, then the whole section is centred, however if none of the taxonomies has enough terms to cover more than 1 line then it is left aligned.

Can anyone think of why it might be doing this and how to fix it?

p.s. Yes I know my codes a little messy, I'm still very new to coding and most of this has been snipped together from different areas, whenever I find something that works. The space before div align, is only there because it wouldn't show on here otherwise for some reason ??

EDIT: It appears the problem occurs due to the `post-meta` class which was part of the original theme coding. Removing this class fixes the alignment problem, but loses all styling for the taxonomies. Any ideas on how to fix this?

CURRENT CODE BELOW

< div align="center">

```
        <div class="post-meta">
        <?php if ( 'post' === get_post_type() && cd_index_meta_cat() ) : ?>
            <span class="post-category">
                <span class= aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="screen-reader-text"><?php esc_html_e( 'Categories', 'coldbox' ); ?></span>
                
                <?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'format','', ', ', '' );?>
            <br>
                    <br>
                <?php the_tags( '<p class="posttag">', ',', '</p>' ); ?>    
                    
                
                <?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'character_tags','', ', ', '' );?>
                
            </span>         <?php endif; ?> </div>  
<br>
</div>
```

Comment: If I remove the `post-meta` class from your second level DIV then it does center. Something in that class makes it go to the left.

Comment: The above comment by KIKO is correct. Currently looking to find a way to remove or change this class without losing font and spacing styles